# Bootstrap 3 Navigation with Search (Responsive Issues)

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, navigation

I've made an example here of where I'm at:
 (http://www.bootply.com/starfox221/8H14cVMlkq#)

Unfortunately, I lose my ability to make it responsive when it scales down to different sizes. Could someone assist me in retaining the same functionality but allow it to also be responsive?

Thanks a heap.

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar-collapsible"> <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
 <span class="icon-bar"></span>

                <span class="icon-bar"></span> <span class="icon-bar"></span>

          </button> <div class="navbar-brand">PetLuvers <i class="fa fa-heart"></i></div>

        </div>

            <div class="navbar-form navbar-right btn-group copernicus">
              <a class="murph" href="#myModal" data-toggle="modal">Login</a>&nbsp;
                 <a class="murph" href="#">Register</a>&nbsp;
                  <a class="murph" href="#">Help</a>&nbsp;
            </div>

     <div class="search">
          <form class="form-inline" role="form">
    <div class="form-group nested-group">
        <input type="text" placeholder="What are you looking for?" id="left-input" class="form-control left">
        <input type="text" placeholder="Zip Code" id="middle-input" class="form-control right">
        <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button">Go!</button>
    </div>
</form>
          </div>





          </div>
          </nav>

    <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true"></button>
                    <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Hey! Welcome back!</h4>
                    </div>
                <div class="modal-body">


    <div class="main">

      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6">
          <a href="#" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block">Facebook</a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6">
          <a href="#" class="btn btn-lg btn-danger btn-block">Google</a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="login-or">
        <hr class="hr-or">
        <span class="span-or">or</span>
      </div>

      <form role="form">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="inputUsernameEmail">Username or email</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputUsernameEmail">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <a class="pull-right" href="#">Forgot password?</a>
          <label for="inputPassword">Password</label>
          <input type="password" class="form-control" id="inputPassword">
        </div>
        <div class="checkbox pull-right">
          <label>
            <input type="checkbox">
            Remember me </label>
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn btn-primary">
          Log In
        </button>
        <br>
       <div class="login-orange">

        <span class="span-orange">Not A PetLuver Yet? Sign up!</span>
      </div>
      </form>

    </div>


</div>

                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <center>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close!</button>
                    </center>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

And the CSS:

```
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway);
.navbar-default {
background-color: #186581;
border-color: #e7e7e7;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-brand {
color: #FFF;
font-weight: bold;
font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;  
}

.navbar>.container .navbar-brand {
margin-left: 150px;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-nav>li>a {
color: #FFFDFD;
}

.btn {

font-size: 14px;
font-weight: bold;
font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;  
text-transform: Uppercase;

}

.fa-heart {
     color: rgb(236, 139, 156);
}

.modal-footer {
padding: 19px 20px 20px;
margin-top: 0px;
text-align: right;
border-top: 0px solid #e5e5e5;
}

.modal-body {
position: relative;
padding: 10px 20px 0px 20px;
}

.modal-title {
margin: 0;
line-height: 1.428571429;
font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif; 
font-weight: Bold;
}


.modal-dialog {
width: 300px !important;
margin: 65px auto;
}


  .nested-group input:focus {
        box-shadow: none;
    }

    .nested-group input:first-child {
        border-bottom-right-radius: 0px;
        border-top-right-radius: 0px;
        border-top-left-radius: 4px;
        border-bottom-left-radius: 4px;
    }

    .nested-group input {
        margin-left: -5px;
        border-radius: 0px;
    }

    .nested-group  button {
        margin-left: -10px;
        border-left: none;
        border-top-left-radius: 0px;
        border-bottom-left-radius: 0px;
    }

.search {
 width: 450px; margin: 10px auto; position relative; 
}

  .left {
     width: 292px;
    }

.right {
   width: 120px;
  }

    .main {
    max-width: 320px;
    margin: 20px auto;
  }
  .login-or {
    position: relative;
    font-size: 18px;
    color: #aaa;
    margin-top: 10px;
            margin-bottom: 10px;
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
  }
  .span-or {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    top: -2px;
    margin-left: -25px;
    background-color: #fff;
    width: 50px;
    text-align: center;
  }
 .span-orange {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    left: 30px;
    top: -2px;
    margin-left: -25px;
    background-color: #fff;
    width: 250px;
    text-align: center;
  }

   .login-orange {
    position: relative;
    font-size: 14px;
    color: #aaa;
    margin-top: 10px;
            margin-bottom: 10px;
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
  }
  .hr-or {
    background-color: #cdcdcd;
    height: 1px;
    margin-top: 0px !important;
    margin-bottom: 0px !important;
  }
  h3 {
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 300%;
  }
  .login-or {
    position: relative;
    font-size: 18px;
    color: #aaa;
    margin-top: 10px;
            margin-bottom: 10px;
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
  }
  .span-or {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    top: -2px;
    margin-left: -25px;
    background-color: #fff;
    width: 50px;
    text-align: center;
  }
  .hr-or {
    background-color: #cdcdcd;
    height: 1px;
    margin-top: 0px !important;
    margin-bottom: 0px !important;
  }
 .signup {
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 300%;
  }

.copernicus {
  font-size: 14px;
font-weight: bold;
font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;  
text-transform: Uppercase;
    color: #FFF;
    margin-top: 15px;
    margin-right: 10%;

  }

  a.murph:link {
  font-size: 14px;
font-weight: bold;
font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;  
text-transform: Uppercase;
    color: #FFF;
    word-spacing: 36px;
       -o-transition:color .2s ease-out, background 1s ease-in;
  -ms-transition:color .2s ease-out, background 1s ease-in;
  -moz-transition:color .2s ease-out, background 1s ease-in;
  -webkit-transition:color .2s ease-out, background 1s ease-in;
  /* ...and now override with proper CSS property */
  transition:color .2s ease-out, background 1s ease-in;
  }

    a.murph:hover {
  font-size: 14px;
font-weight: bold;
font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;  
text-transform: Uppercase;
    color: #A7ADB2;
    word-spacing: 36px;
      text-decoration: none;
  }
```

Comment: Post your code here instead of giving a link.Its not good way to ask question at SO

Comment: Please post the minimum required code to illustrate the issue (In the question - a link to a live example is useful but not everyone can access it). Also, can you describe in greater detail what the functionality you want / the issue you have is?

Comment: How do you want the navbar to be in small screens? Please post a pic or something..

Comment: Hi, I added the code. Sorry about that. Essentially I would like the search bar to be present on top once it starts to scale down to smaller screens (i.e. Phones and Tablets) and have the menu links be directly below that. So..it would be logo, search bar, and then links all centered.